# Is it possible to start company completion without a prefix?

Tags: completion, company-mode, css

Autocompletion is particularly useful in writing CSS, to see the available options for a given property. Company provides `company-minimum-prefix-length` to control how many characters I have to type before it starts offering options.

However, I want completion without any characters, so I get this:

[image: company mode completion of css]

Currently, I can only get this by either:

1. Explicitly calling `M-x company-complete`
2. Setting `(setq company-minimum-prefix-length 0)`, typing a single character and backspace, e.g. `a DEL`.

Is this possible? Ideally I'd be able to do it for both properties and their values.

Comment: The problem, though is that completion would _always_ be on. It would be on for properties, and selectors at least. There are so many properties, that completion without a prefix would not be very helpful, and would just take up screen space. So do you want context-sensitive completion properties?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it's contextual: I though about advising self-insert-command to trigger completion on space, but that only helps for values. Though I think completion without prefix is useful, even for properties. (I learn more CSS and the dropdown shows more than 10 with a scrollbar).

Comment: "typing a single character and backspace" Why this? With `company-minimum-prefix-length` set to 0, you will already see the completion popup after typing space. Not after pressing return, though.

Comment: @Dmitry I'm not seeing that behaviour. What version of company are you using?

Comment: @WilfredHughes master.

Comment: "I want completion without any characters"

Did you find a solution without explicitly requesting completion?

Comment: Nevermind. In my case, comint-magic-space was not whitelisted and prevented completions. All good now. Happy days.

Answer (score 5):

I use TAB to trigger company-mode on demand in cases like that -- it works fine in your CSS example. I also use TAB to indent (`tab-always-indent` set to `complete`). You can integrate company with the built-in `indent-for-tab-command` using the configuration described here:
https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/94#issuecomment-40884387

Here is the relevant code from the linked github comment:

```el
(define-key company-mode-map [remap indent-for-tab-command]
  'company-indent-for-tab-command)

(setq tab-always-indent 'complete)

(defvar completion-at-point-functions-saved nil)

(defun company-indent-for-tab-command (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((completion-at-point-functions-saved completion-at-point-functions)
        (completion-at-point-functions '(company-complete-common-wrapper)))
    (indent-for-tab-command arg)))

(defun company-complete-common-wrapper ()
  (let ((completion-at-point-functions completion-at-point-functions-saved))
    (company-complete-common)))
```

Answer (score 3):

As of recent versions of `company`, this is the way to go:

```
(define-key company-mode-map [remap indent-for-tab-command] #'company-indent-or-complete-common)
```